# Is there a way to "print" the values of two accelerators simultaneously?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, accelerometer, i2c, adafruit-circuitpython

I'm a beginner at coding and all that buzz so this might seem a silly question.
I'm trying to "print" the values (x,y,z) of two accelerometers (LIS3DH) connected with I2C to a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.I'm directly coding on the Rasp (on Thonny) and I don't know how to differentiate the values of the two. I need those values simoultaneously since I want to code about the difference between the two and that can't be done since the code I'm using through Adafruit's libraries only displays the values of one of the accelerometers.
Here's the code :

```
import adafruit_lis3dh
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import busio
import time
import digitalio
import board

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
int1=digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D18)
lis3dh = adafruit_lis3dh.LIS3DH_I2C(i2c)

x,y,z=lis3dh.acceleration
print (x,y,z)
```

Thank you !

Comment: You will need to change the i2c address of one of the devices. And since, you need to read them one at a time, you can't quite get truly simultaneous readings, but you can get close if you read both values before you do any processing.

Comment: How strong *simultaneously* should be? I.o.w. how big time delta in readings you would like to achieve?

Comment: @NomadMaker The two accelerators both have different I2C addresses already. Is there a way to get both their values one after the other without having to change the connexion then?

Comment: @0andriy it's to measure the angle of your knee when running so the time in between readings would be the time between your knee at it's max angle and the next one.

Comment: No, but the difference will be extremely small. Just don't do any processing of the values between the two readings.

Comment: @NomadMaker alright, but I don't know how to make the code "remember" the first reading after having done the second since they both have their acceleration as "lis3dh.acceleration" and I believe it is reset after the reading of the first values.

Comment: Store them in an array, or just as two different variables?

Comment: Could you do edit your question with the output of lsi2c? You'll have to format this output like code. Also, what are the i2c addresses of your two sensors?